# Determining a preimage of the connecting homomorphism of the Mayer Vietoris sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

In this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence, and in the section about the  connecting homomorphism associated to a Mayer-Vietoris sequence, the connecting homomorphhism $\partial_*$ is defined by:

$$H_{n}(X) \xrightarrow{\partial_*}\,H_{n-1} (A\cap B)$$

My problem is the following. Suppose we have a class in  $Im(\partial_*)\subset H_{n-1}(A\cap B)$ and we want to determine one of the preimages of this class in $H_{n}(X)$, is there a general way to find this preimage, knowing that the map $\partial:X\rightarrow A\cap B$ from which $\partial_*$ is induced is not known in general or maybe need not exist!!

Comment: How do you know that a homology class is in the image of $\partial_*$ if you don not know of any preimage? Also note that the connecting homomorphism $\partial_*$ is never induced by a continuous map $X\to A\cap B$. It is rather defined algebraically.

Comment: Because the sequence is exact so if a class is in the kernel $\subset H_{n-1}(A\cap B)$ then it must be in the image of $\partial_*$. Is there a way how to do explict computations of this connecting homomorphism, especially determining one of the preimages of a class in the kernel $\subset H_{n-1}(A\cap B)$